# how to use mongoose aggregate to search an array within a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, aggregate

I am trying to group by products in my sales collection and add their totals to know which are the best selling products of my app.

**MONGOOSE MODEL**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

const DHCustomerinvoiceSchema = mongoose.Schema({

```
    Saledetail: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }, 
    date:{
       type: Date,
       required: true     
   },
   total:{
        type: Number,
        required: true  
   },
   pay:{
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: 0 
   },
   topay:{
     type: Number,
     required: true 
   },
   user:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'UserDH'
   },
   customer:{
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       required: true,
       ref: 'DHcontacto'
   },
   state:{
       type: String,
       default: "OWED"  
   },
   created:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
   },


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('DHCustomerinvoice', DHCustomerinvoiceSchema);
```

**COLLECTION EXAMPLE**

```
{
    "id": "5ef6*****",
    "Saledetail": [
      {
        "id": "5ebf*****",
        "quantity": 9,
        "price": 2000,
        "totalline": 18000
      }
    ],
    "datesale": "1593129600000",
    "grandtotal": 18000,
    "user": "5eb9ab******",
    "customer": {
      "name": "isabella"
    },
    "state": "PAID"
  },
```

**RESOLVER:**

```
mostSellingProducts: async (_,{},ctx)=>{   
    
                const Products = await invoice.aggregate([
                     { $unwind: "$Saledetail" },
                     { $match: { "state" : 'PAID'}},
                     { $group: {
                        _id : "$Saledetail.id",
                        total: { $sum: '$Saledetail.totalline' }
                    }},
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'dhproducts',
                            localField: '_id',
                            foreignField: "_id",
                            as: "producto" 
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $limit: 4
                    },
                    {
                        $sort : {total: -1}
                    }
                    ]);
                console.log(Products);
                return Products;
   },
```

I have used many methods that actually did not give me this result, but nevertheless I have achieved a positive result in terms of finding my best clients who actually develop it with aggregate, match and group also apply sort and limit ...
but with this example I have not been able to achieve success, and I imagine that it is because the architecture of the collection is distinguished due to the arrangement of the purchase detail

Comment: Hi, you are performing grouping by `$producto` field, but I don't see this key in your collection example. You introduce this field later when performing `lookup`. Also if you will translate field names to English it will be simpler to give you an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, I have already followed your recommendation and translated everything into English ... I look forward to any solution you can give me and again thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below the answer to my question

```
mostSellingProducts: async (_,{},ctx)=>{   
    
                const Products = await Invoice.aggregate([
                     { $unwind: "$Saledetail" },
                     { $match: { "state" : 'PAY'}},
                     { $group: {   
                        _id : { $toObjectId: "$Saledetail.id" },
                        total: { $sum: '$Saledetail.totalline' }
                    }},
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'dhproducts',
                            localField: '_id',
                            foreignField: "_id",
                            as: "products" 
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $limit: 4
                    },
                    {
                        $sort : {total: -1}
                    }
                    ]);
                return Products;
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question. So I am sharing this as an answer.

I think you can use $elemMatch to search for the item in an array.

```
const Productos = await Factura.aggregate([{ detlle: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 80, $lt: 85 } } }])
```

For more detailed info [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)